# Finding all the points (x, y) where the slope of the tangent line is -1 and 1.

Tags: calculus

I'm given an astroid with the parametric equations $x = 6cos^3t, y = 6sin^3t$.

In order to find the slope of the tangent line itself, I divided the derivative of y in terms of t over the derivative of x in terms of t, hence $\frac {dy/dt}{dx/dt} = \frac{dy}{dx}$. This gave me $-tan(t)$, which is the slope of the tangent line to the astroid in terms of t.

However, now I'm being asked to list all of the points $(x, y)$ where the slope of the tangent line is 1 and -1. At first I believed it was just going to be as easy as setting it up like $-tan(t) = 1, -tan(t) = -1$, but theres no set values for those $x$'s, or $t$'s in this case.

Is there another way to go about this problem? Any kind of guidance on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are infinite solutions to $\tan(t)=\pm 1$; however, your function is periodic, so there should be 4 solutions in terms of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: So how would I use that value to find the desired $(x,y)$ points?

Comment: To go once around the curve, we go $t=0$ (inclusive) to $2\pi$ (exclusive). There are $4$ places where $\tan t=\pm 1$. The first is $\pi/4$, the second $3\pi/4$, and so on. Calculate $(x,y)$ for each.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that in a sense there are no *set* values for $t$ when $\tan(t)=\pm1$ because there are infinite solutions. However, your function is periodic with period of $2\pi$ so there a finite solutions in terms of $x$ and $y$. This becomes more clear when you look at a plot.

[image: plot]

We only need to find $t$ when it restricted to $[0,2\pi]$ due to the periodicity of the function and then our $x$ and $y$ values from there.

We know $\tan(t)=1$. With our restriction, this means $t=\pi/4$ and $t=5\pi/4$. Again, these are the only solutions we care about. For $\tan(t)=-1$, $t=3\pi/4$ and $t=7\pi/4$. Now we can substitute these $t$ values back to our original function in order to find the $(x,y)$ points. We obtain (due to the symmetry of the problem)

$$(x,y)=\left(\pm\frac{3}{\sqrt 2}, \pm\frac{3}{\sqrt 2}\right)$$